# Accessing NS2 packet header to get received data in a wireless network

Tags: c++, tcl, ns2

I have an encryption protocol implemented in NS2 (Elliptic curve to be exact). I built a wireless network in TCL. The cc code encrypts the message that it got from the TCL then stores the encrypted data in a packet header and sends it to another node. The other node is supposed to retrieve this data and decrypts it to the original plaintext.
I have a problem when the second node receives the wireless packet and accesses the header to retrieve the encrypted data (so it can preform the decryption), the received data is modified.
**for an example:**
=> if I want to send a message "abc" (The message will be converted to integers for encryption) , the first node encrypts the message  and it and stores it in the packet header. When I print the encrypted data in the header before sending I get "508550885090".

=> When the second node receives the packet in the recv function, the header content changes to "107780505601550881290"
How can I extract the original sent data from the wireless packet header?

Here is the recv part from the code that accesses the header:

```
void Security_packetAgent::recv(Packet * pkt, Handler * ) {

  // Access the IP header for the received packet:
  hdr_ip * hdrip = hdr_ip::access(pkt);

  // Access the security packet header for the received packet:
  hdr_security_packet * hdr = hdr_security_packet::access(pkt);
  //code for storing the data and handling it

}
```

Where hdr_security_packet is in the header file for the encryption protocol  and the recieved encrypted data is stored in hdr.
Any help is appreciated.
Thanks in advance.